# shows readme page after deploying react-app

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment

I deployed react-app to GitHub, and when I open it, it shows readme page

[image]

I followed these commands

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'upload'
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/charyyev2000/React-Quiz-App.git
git push -u origin main
```

I added the homepage to my package.json
[image]

Comment: did you use gh-pages ??

Comment: No, I just followed those commands, nothing else

Comment: those commands are for creating repo not deploying

Comment: what should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i will list down the steps for deployment :

1 `npm i gh-pages`  inside your root dir

2 add this to your package.json

```
"scripts": {
//...
"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
}
```

3 then run this cmd

```
npm run deploy
```